# Django and sqlite email authentication

Tags: django, sqlite, email, authentication

I wanted to create an email authenticated django user model, and I basically followed the steps in this website:
http://www.micahcarrick.com/django-email-authentication.html
And also included the table alteration code in a post_syncdb function in a managmenet module, to make the email a unique identifier. This should work ok with MySql. BUT, it wont work for sqlite. This is because sqlite's table alteration is limited and wont allow you to change that attribute OR even add a column with a unique identifier.

If there is no elegant way of doing this, then I might have to switch to MySql.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q26

So, it UNIQUE is fully supported, but you cannot alter a table using UNIQUE.  So dump the table to a new table that has the UNIQUE constraint then alter and rename the tables.  Or just dump it, modify the dump and reimport it.

Comment: The Table is automatically generated by the Django ORM which is using the model class. I'd have to manually go and do the alteration as I believe, or it's possible that I'm wrong and it is doable in the post_syncdb function?

Answer (score 0):

I think, in your post_syncdb hook, you can add:

```
cursor.execute(
    "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS auth_user_email_unique "
    "ON auth_user (email COLLATE NOCASE);"
)
```

you may have to break out different blocks based on `settings.DATABASES['default']['ENGINE']`